# Open Lollipop Interruption screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

How can I launch an intent to open the Lollipop Interruption settings?

[image]

Comment: It seems like you can't open Interruption Settings Intent but you can just open Sound Settings and from there user will have to open Interruptions. You can see all the Action Intents here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html